# Find mount point by device UUID

Tags: linux, block-device

I have device UUID like from blkid:

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="5db99adc-11d3-482d-af80-1985dac704b1" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="000f2b58-01"
```

I search a tool which I can give `5db99adc-11d3-482d-af80-1985dac704b1`, and it should return me the mount point of this device.

Comment: Read `man lsblk`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use "df" for this:

> df /dev/disk/by-uuid/5db99adc-11d3-482d-af80-1985dac704b1

Main interest is that this can work with old systems, or lsblk like Sven said (but why not answer @Sven ?) which is a bit more helpful:

> lsblk --noheadings --output MOUNTPOINT /dev/disk/by-uuid/5db99adc-11d3-482d-af80-1985dac704b1

Comment: `lsblk` with noheadings and output MOUNTPOINT are great. Thank you.